# Having trouble reading in data from OECD using XML2Obs (XML2R package)

Tags: xml, r

I have an SDMX query that *was* working just fine about a month ago, but now suddenly it breaks with the error:

> Error in rapply(docs, function(x) getNodeSet(x, path = xpath), classes = c("XMLInternalDocument",  : 
>     'object' must be a list

I tried loading the page using a browser and it seems to return XML data, although I don't really know enough about XML to figure out what might be going wrong. Here's the code:

```
library(XML2R)

sdmx <- paste0("http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/FDI_FLOW_AGGR/",
           "AUS+AUT+BEL+CAN+CHL+CZE+DNK+EST+FIN+FRA+DEU+GRC+HUN+ISL+IRL+ISR",
           "+ITA+JPN+KOR+LUX+MEX+NLD+NZL+NOR+POL+PRT+SVK+SVN+ESP+SWE+CHE+TU",
           "R+GBR+USA+G20_OECD+G20_NON_OECD+EU+G20+OECD+WLD+NMEC+ARG+BRA+CH",
           "N+IND+IDN+RUS+SAU+ZAF.USD+SUB.A+DI+DO.T_FA_F.ALL+ROU.NET+A+L.D/",
           "all?startTime=2005&endTime=2015-Q4")

xmlobs <- XML2Obs(sdmx, quiet=TRUE)
tables <- collapse_obs(xmlobs)
```

It breaks on XML2Obs, so I guess there's no need for the last line, but you get the point, anyway.

Any idea what might be going on? Or how I can easily switch to a different XML reader? My concern is that it wasn't exactly easy to convert the mess that comes in from XML2R into a usable data frame, so if I switch to a different XML parser, it might end up in a very different shape when it goes into R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue faced with `XML2R` seems due to the fact the data is not correctly fetched in R as XML object. I had a look to `XML2R`, debugging the above request.

Recently, OECD.Stats made a change to the SDMX API, introducing a Bytes Order Mark (BOM) in the SDMX responses: It seems that the BOM is not managed in dependencies used by `XML2R`, at least it seems the reason of failure for the OECD request: The dependency in cause seems to be the `curl` package which is used in `XML2R` through the `httr` package `GET` method.

The expected object returned by the `GET` method should of class `"XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"` (expected by `XML2R`).

However, in the case of the OECD request, it returns an object of class `raw`. Similar issue is raised with SDMX EUROSTAT requests (e.g. http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/data/cdh_e_fos/..PC.FOS1.BE/?startperiod=2005&endPeriod=2011), but here the reason is different and involves the `XML2R` package itself: To make it work with all XML files (whatever the mimetype of the XML web request), `XML2R` should not get the `GET` `content` as `text`, but specify explicitely the `text/xml` mimetype (as indicates the `content` documentation). This is also required (but not enough) to fix the OECD issue (a fix upstream, probably in `curl`, is required)

As quick alternative, i suggest to consider using the `rsdmx` package, whose package is specifically targeting the reading of SDMX data and metadata documents in `R`.

FYI, `rsdmx` is not relying on `curl` and `httr`, but on `RCurl`. Regarding the newly appended BOM to OECD requests, a fix was recently released in `rsdmx` to check the presence of a BOM and remove it. Then `rsdmx` guarantees a proper reading of SDMX XML object in R, and its interpretation as `R` `SDMX` object.

Hope this clarifies

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I already used rsdmx anyway, but glad to know that something changed between when I wrote the code in June and now.

Comment: i've updated my answer. One related issue is that ``XML2R`` uses ``content`` to retrieve a ``text``, while it should rather get ``xml`` directly. This supposes to cover all possible ``xml`` mime sub types, by specify directly the ``text/xml`` mime type as argument of ``content`` ``httr`` function

Answer (score 0):

You can try using RJSDMX (on CRAN or Github) and avoid parsing the XML at all. Just use the getTimeSeries function with your query and, if you need a data.frame, call the function sdmxdf on the result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using rsdmx, but that did require rewriting a bunch of the code, since it came back in a different format. I still wonder what happened, since it worked a month ago.

Comment: I noticed that this month the OECD xml streams started having a BOM at the start. Maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: Could be. I managed to get it to work on a different data set (also from OECD), but this one still doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Phil can you try to upgrade to the latest rsdmx version in CRAN (0.4-7) and tell me if it works? Some control has been added in order to detect BOM zs recently the OECF portal came with some changes in the way they handle  SDMX xml data.

Comment: @Phil I've tested your request and it works fine with rsdmx 0.4-7, it's highly probable that it was the issue of BOM highlighted by @amattioc here above. The function ``XML2Obs`` may miss such control to detect the BOM, recently added in ``rsdmx`` to deal with the changes operated by OECD. Then you can use ``rsdmx`` safely, although as you said you will have to adapt your code to deal with the difference of R data structure.

Comment: Ah, yes, I gave up and started using rsdmx with it last week. Unsurprisingly, it worked as well/better than the XML2R, since after all, its purpose is to read SDMX and not just any XML file. I only left the question unanswered because I still don't know why XML2R isn't working.

Comment: @Phil As follow-up, if you still use rsdmx, in the next version to be released in CRAN (0.5, available at now in Github), you can query known data providers in an easier way, without having to specify the entire SDMX request URL. OECD is one of the data providers configured by default with rsdmx: see https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/blob/master/vignettes/quickstart.Rmd#using-the-helper-approach

Comment: Oh, that's great. I've been having a lot of problems configuring these different services. The IMF site didn't work at all.